# Android drawable layer-list item size not working on API < 23

Tags: android, xml

I have a calendar that should show small dots on days that have an event. I'm using a drawable that draws the small dots.

This works great on my Nexus device with android 6.0, but if i try it on a device with 5.0 installed, it does not work. The dot fills the entire container.

Attached is a screenshot of the bug. The two large blue circles should be 4px small dots.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:height="4dp" android:width="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I am calling this drawable like this ("@drawable/date_default_event_stroke" is the code above):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:caldroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/date_default_event_stroke" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have called this xml in some background,
like android:background=@drawable/xml.
so this will be appilied to entire view.
You have to create class which extends any view and create the custom circle.

Comment: I've updated my question with how i'm calling that XML. I am quite new to Android development, so do you have any hits to point me in the right direction here?

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/android/how-to-draw-circle-in-android-view-ondraw-canvas

use this link to create circle in your project with the expected size. then add this circle in xml where ever you want.